# CKEDITOR is being disabled when a new editor is pulled onto page, how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ckeditor, updatepanel

I have a CKEDITOR textarea on a page, and a second editor inside an update panel on the same page. When the update panel updates, it replaces the old editor with a new one and that works fine. But, when this happens it essentially wipes out the other editor on the page, and you cannot enter text into it. All the CK attributes that were on that editor go away. Is there anyway to re-enable that disabled editor when the update panel refreshes?

Comment: The way I solved this was by creating a hidden field and saving the info in the field before I send data to the server - and restore it afterwards.  I didn't use update panel, however.